# layout grid on card css , i want the price and button in the bottom left and right

Tags: html, css, layout

help me to layout my container, i want `<h3 class="price">35.000</h3>` in the bottom left and `<div class="card-btn"><button class="btn" >ADD +</button> </div>` in the bottom right but this happen [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXEc2.jpg)

```css
.flex-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 80px;
    grid-template-areas: "image" "text" "btn";
    border-radius: 18px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 10px rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.1);
    font-family: roboto, serif;
    margin: 16px;
}

.card-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 16px;
}

.card-text p {
    font-size: small;
    color: grey;
}

.card-btn {
    grid-area: btn;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    float: right;
}

.btn {
    background: #f9234a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 0.5px white;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
}

.card-image01 {
    grid-area: image;
    background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image01"></div>
        <div class="card-text">
            <h3> Nasi Rames </h3>
            <p> by kunia app</p>
            <h3 class="price">35.000</h3>
            <div class="card-btn">
                <button class="btn">ADD +</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

Add a div having a class(flex) inside the price and button

```html
<div class="flex">
    <h3 class="price">35.000</h3>
    <div class="card-btn">
        <button class="btn">ADD +</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add to flex class

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Result :

[image]

```css
.flex-container {
  align-items:center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 80px;
  grid-template-areas: "image" "text" "btn" ;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.1);
  font-family: roboto;
  margin:16px;
} 
.card-text{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.card-text p{
  font-size: small;
  color: grey;
}
.card-btn{
  grid-area: btn;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  float: right;
}
.btn{
  background:#f9234a;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 0.5px white;
  padding:4px 20px;
  color: white;
  align-items:center;
}
.card-image01 {
  grid-area: image;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyl4g.png);
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  background-size: cover;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class= "card">
    <div class="card-image01"></div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3> Nasi Rames </h3>
      <p> by kunia app</p>
      <div class="flex">
        <h3 class="price">35.000</h3>
        <div class="card-btn">
          <button class="btn" >ADD +</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you want like this @dipretelin?

Comment: that is , big thaaankkss dudeee

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: "image" "text" "btn";
    border-radius: 18px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 10px rgba(10, 31, 68, 0.1);
    font-family: roboto;

    margin: 16px;
}
.card-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
.card-text p {
    font-size: small;
    color: grey;
    grid-area: btn;
}
.card-btn {
    grid-area: text;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.btn {
    background: #f9234a;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 0.5px white;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
}
.card-image01 {
    grid-area: image;
    background: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image01"></div>
        <div class="card-text">
            <h3>Nasi Rames</h3>
            <p>by kunia app</p>

            <div class="card-btn">
                <span class="price">35.000</span>

                <button class="btn">ADD +</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```